Node-Tools: Assign attribute to instance?
The new node-based tools are awesome, but how can we assign attributes to objects outside of their geometry domains (vertices, edges, splines etc.)? I'm trying to write attributes on a per-instance basis. But it seems anything instance-related that isn't realized by the end of the node tree gets ignored, so it can't be used later on by a node-modifier or shader.
